# Sidebar Mini cart overlay not working propely

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created Sidebar for `mini cart woocommerce`, When user click on `"Shopping Cart"` icon on navbar menu then Mini Cart Sidebar opens.
I tried to add `screen overlay` in close button which is in sidebar, but it's not working properly, it has spread to full screen, but i want it to spread on full screen expect Sidebar.
I tried to add `z-index: 999`, but not worked.
**Here are some screenshots: Please check**

[image]

**After Click on Shopping Cart Icon:**

[image]

**See, It has spread to full screen. I tried to do increase z-index: 999, but did not work.**

**Here are my code:**
**Html:**

```
<div>
   <label class="shopping-cart mb-0"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart text-white"></i></label>
</div>
<div class="miniCartSidebar z-depth-2">
    <button class="btn close-mini-cart"></button>
    <h4>Shopping Cart</h4>
    <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content pl-3">
        <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.miniCartSidebar {
    width: 420px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    right: -420px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.miniCartSidebar.show{
    right: 0;
}

.close-mini-cart:after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

.close-mini-cart.opened:after {
    display: block;
}
```

Please help me, I have tried a lot. I am stuck. Please help me

Comment: Share URL if it's live so might be we can help you.

Comment: Brother, It's not live

Comment: Try to set your popup position top:100%

Comment: create a fiddle and upload u r code and attack link @Zain